# How to make a linethrough, or a strike on a word on click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, strikethrough

I'm using the following JS code on a separate file to make a list by entering words in a text field and pressing a button:

```
function newElement() {

  var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value
  var listNode = document.getElementById('myUL'),
  var liNode = document.createElement('LI'),
  var txtNode = document.createTextNode(myInput);

  liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);

}
```

Everything works fine but I need to click every new word and change it by let's say, adding a strike on this word. What I'm trying to make is a checklist.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do so is to remove the item from it's parent element, append an `<s>` tag, and append the item to the `<s>` tag. That's the procedure. If you could give the actual code and details, I could give you a complete answer

Comment: I doubt one can call the use of some long deprecated appearance related tags as "*the best way*"

Comment: Also, the s tag was depreciated in html 4 but remade in html 5

Comment: thanks for noticing, I din't know that

Comment: actually, I knew that, but forgot

Comment: you're sure, that your opinion is very important to us

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171571/discussion-between-electrox-qui-mortem-and-user907860).

Comment: Some would argue the <del> tag has replaced <s>

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `setProperty()` method to switch the element's `text-decoration` to `line-through`

```js
function strikeIt() {

  let el = document.querySelector('.target');
  el.style.setProperty('text-decoration', 'line-through');
  
}
```

```html
<div class="target">Hello</div>
<button onclick="strikeIt()">Click me</button>
```